# Алгоритм, код вычисления единиц измерения

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста как выглядит код для работы с единицами измерения?

Ну к примеру нужно выполнить некоторые алгебраические операции над несколькими числа, выраженными в определенных единицах измерения. И в итоге нужно получить не только число, но и его единицу измерения. Как такой алгоритм выглядит?

Comment: @СуперАлексей, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос.

Comment: У Вас в слове "Код" ошибка, вместо буквы "т" написана буква "д"! :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Units

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то вам надо производить некие операции с числами которые могут представлять параметры в розличных единицах измерения. Единственное не понятно где и как указываются ваши единицы измерения, так что пока определим что какие то единицы измерения заданы все таки изначально но их надо привести к одному множителю, например:

```
10м. + 30см. + 600мм. = 1м. + 0,3м. + 0,6м. = 1,9м.
```

Я бы в этом случае предложил бы объектный подход, т.е. каждое число это наследник примерно такого интерфейса:

```
public interface INumInCI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// заданное значение
    /// </summary>
    double Value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// текущий множитель
    /// </summary>
    double Factor { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Список множителей, например для метров
    /// 0.001, "мм."
    /// 0.01, "см."
    /// 0.1, "дм."
    /// 1, "м."
    /// 1000, "км."
    /// </summary>
    Dictionary<double, string> FactorList { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// возвращает значение с множителеи 1
    /// с учетом того что текущее значение и текущий множитель извесны
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    double Get_CI_Value();
}
```

и ко всему этому надо будет приделать редактор для ввода выражения с указанием вводимых величин, либо хороший парсер с проверкой вводимых данных, это уже на ваш вкус.